# One Piece: Why didn't Spandam eat the Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

Note: I watched the anime, but did not read the manga.

In the Enies Lobby Arc, once the CP9 members return to Enies Lobby, Spandam gives a devil fruit to both Kaku and Kalifa.

But WHY?

Based on his childish and narcissistic attitude, I feel like he would want to eat them to be strong enough to do whatever he wanted. It seems out of character for him to give them both to someone, rather than use one of them himself. He loved having power over others, flaunting that power, and using it to cause pain to others. Was there an explanation I missed, or maybe the manga explained it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He didn't eat them because he didn't know what Devil Fruit they were other than that they were Zoan type, so he was scared to take the gamble. He wanted to eat a powerful fruit that he knows before eating; that was why he refused to eat one and gave them away.

If he eats one, then it is his one and only chance and only that Devil Fruit power can be used in his lifetime, even if he hates it. This fact scared him.

Comment: While accurate, you might consider adding a source to your answer to help solidify it.

Comment: I actually hadn't thought of that! He HAS read the encyclopedia, so it makes complete sense! Thank you for that!

Comment: If Spandam didn't know exactly which devil fruits he had on hand he wouldn't know if they were zoan, paramecia, logia type because it has never been established you can tell the type without knowing the exact fruit. Ergo, he couldn't have known he had 2 zoan fruit, if he thought he did then he was wrong because Kalifa's bubble bubble fruit is paramecia